# How can I send value to Actionscript using Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I want to send a `float` variable to Actionscript.

I use `window.document.setVariable()`, but it only supports type `String`, and ignores `0` and point (`.`)

I try to use `parseFloat()` and `value * 1` in javascript,but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague. Still, here goes:

There are 2 (edited to **3**) methods to get a variable into Flash from the html. Both use the `ExternalInterface` class

(1): Pull the variable into ActionScript

```
//JavaScript:
var myVariable=3.14159; //or whatever you want to set it as

function getMyVariable() {
    return myVariable;
}


//Flash
var myVariable:Number=ExternalInterface.call("getMyVariable");
```

(2): Push the variable into ActionScript

```
//Flash
ExternalInterface.addCallback("pushVar", varPushed);
var myVariable:Number=0;
function varPushed(x:Number):void {
    myVariable=x;
}



//JavaScript
var myVariable=3.14159; //or whatever you want to set it as
var fl = document.getElementById('myflashobject');
fl.pushVar(myVariable);
```

**EDIT**
(3): Use flashVars

If you use swfObject, then you add flashVars using the following line:

```
var flashvars = {}; 
    flashvars.myVariable=3.14159
...
...
swfobject.embedSWF( 
    "FlashVarTest.swf", "flashContent", "100%", "100%", swfVersionStr, 
    xiSwfUrlStr, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

If you use the `<object>` tag then you add flashVars like this:

```
 <object id='mySwf' classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' height='100%' width='100%'>
        <param name='src' value='FlashVarTest.swf'/>
        <param name='flashVars' value='myVariable=3.14159'/>
        <embed name='mySwf' src='FlashVarTest.swf' height='100%' width='100%' flashVars='myVariable=3.14159'/>
    </object>
```

Regardless of your embedding method, you access flashVars in AS3 like this:

If you are using the Flex SDK:

```
var myVariable:Number = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.myVariable;
```

If you are not using the Flex SDK:

```
var myVariable:Number =Number(LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters.myVariable);
```

Comment: Those are not the only ways. You can also use flashvars, which is what the OP is trying to do I think.

Comment: @JonatanHedborg, the question is not very clear, but yeah. I'll shortly add the FlashVars part to my answer

Comment: @JonatanHedborg, how does it look now?