# login from php to flex project

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying create system in which I can login from php and then go directly to the flex project. The flex project already has login system but I want to bypass that and use the login system created in php. For testing I created a simple mxml file and one html page. Using the object tag and flashvars I passed the username and password into the swf and displayed using label. But my project is very big and want to pass username and password without using the swf of the project. Is that possible?

Comment: What does the size of a project have to do with logging in or passing variables to a Flex-generated SWF app?

Comment: I mean that the project has several libraries , so could not compile it into swf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but still, here goes nothing:

**My understanding**:

You have a flex app, and you want to restrict access to it using password validation in php

**My solution:**

1. Create a simple login form, which submits to login.php
2. Create a application.php, which will display the flex app

login.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        //check for valid username and password
        if( /* valid login */ ) {
            $_SESSION['isloggedin']=true;
            header("Location: application.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['isloggedin']=false;
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['isloggedin']=false;
    }
?>
```

application.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['isloggedin']) && $_SESSION['isloggedin']) {
        include("./myFlexAppPage.html");
    } else {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Pranav this myFlexAppPage.html is inside the bin-debug folder of the flex project. How can I include that file into the server directory?

Comment: Obviously, you'll have to upload it to the server, and put the login.php and application.php in the same directory as myFlexAppPage.html

Comment: Hi Pranav so now I have to authenticate using php server. Run the Flex project set the view stack to the logged-in view and upload the files into the server directory. Then after authenticating I can go directly into the loggedIn view.

Comment: You can actually just set the Flex app to the logged in view and publish it. The php script will take care of the rest.

Comment: Hi Pranav how will I passed the user credentials to the Flex project. I have different privileges for different users for the Flex project.

Comment: That you can do using FlashVars. I trust you know how to use FlashVars.

Comment: But in that case, it would be a better solution to just do the validation in the Flex app instead of going through php

Comment: I know how to pass values into swf file using FlashVars, but how to pass those values into the application.html file which I am including.

Comment: The application.html file is using swfObject.It is by default I think and it also using object tags. When flashvars are used then swfobject is not required only object tags are required.

Comment: I just removed swfobject related code from the head and put the object tags into the div tag. Now I am getting the username, password into the project. I don't know whether it will create any problem later.

Comment: No, I don't think there should create a problem

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200861/how-can-i-send-value-to-actionscript-using-javascript/8200958#8200958 for how to use flashvars using swfobject