# dynamically embeded variable in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

My requirement is not to dynamically embed fonts in Flex, but to dynamically embed variable in Flex.For example:
Code:

```
<fx:Script>
    [Bindable]
    [Embed(source=myPath)]
    private var _china:Class;
</fx:Script>
```

the background will pass the variable myPath to the flex

Answer (score 3):

The point of embedding something is to include it in the swf DURING compile time. There is no such thing as dynamically embedding a resource.

Comment: I want to pass the source path when the application is running. How it can achieve? Do you have other way to make it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200861/how-can-i-send-value-to-actionscript-using-javascript/8200958#8200958 for how to pass data to a running swf

Answer (score 0):

Embedding concept is do embed the image within the swf which is doable only in the design time (comile-time).

What you are asking is beyond the current capabilities of flex/action script.

May be you should look for alternative ways out there. Example, dynamically loading the image using Loader() class.